# Any suggestion to tune this query using group by function

Tags: sql, sql-server

I am trying to simplify this query using group by but got stuck. Any suggestions?

```
SELECT Distinct  Model,Age,Gender,
      (Select count(Gender) From [EDW].[sio].[TB_R_SURVEY_IN_OPERATION] g Where         
          g.Model = t.Model And Gender <> 'NULL') Total_Gender,
      (Select count(Gender) From [EDW].[sio].[TB_R_SURVEY_IN_OPERATION] g Where         
          g.Model = t.Model AND Gender = 'Laki-Laki') Male_Gender,
      (Select count(Gender) From [EDW].[sio].[TB_R_SURVEY_IN_OPERATION]                       
          g Where g.Model = t.Model AND Gender = 'Perempuan') Female_Gender,
      (Select Count(Age) From [EDW].[sio].[TB_R_SURVEY_IN_OPERATION]                         
         t1 Where t1.Model = t.Model AND t1.Age = t.Age AND (t1.Age <> 'NULL' AND t1.Age IS 
              NOT NULL)) Age_Count
from [EDW].[sio].[TB_R_SURVEY_IN_OPERATION]  t
```

Comment: This query looks weird. You are showing rows per gender and columns per gender. That doesn't seem to make much sense. Please tell us what exactly the query is supposed to do. Show some sample data and the expected result. Then tell us about your table: What does it represent? What is its key? Are there really strings containing the word 'NULL' in your table?

Comment: What do you mean "simplify"? less code? What did you get stuck on?

Answer (score 0):

Your request is very vague. I understand this as: "My query is almost doing what I want it to do, but somehow the result is not as well structured as I want it to be. Please help me get a grip on this."

You select one row per model, age and gender. For this to happen we would usually `GROUP BY model, age, gender`, but you are rather using `DISTINCT`, because you are doing the aggregations in subqueries, and the aggregations only partly refer to the group. So for instance you show a row for model = A, age = 30, gender = male, but the counts show

- the model's total count for all genders and ages
- the model's males count, no matter what age
- the model's females count, no matter what age
- and at last the model's and age's overall count (i.e. regardless of the gender).

The next row may be for model = A, age = 30, gender = *female*, and you'll show exactly the same figures. And a row for model = A, age = *100*, gender = female will show the same figures again, except for the age count.

What you must do here is think about what result you really want. Take a paper, draw a table, fill it with the desired result. You will see that you either want one result row per model and age and gender (`GROUP BY model, age, gender`) or per model and age (`GROUP BY model, age`). Then do your counting. `COUNT(*)` simply counts the rows for the group, and it's likely you are interested in the group's count.

Then you can get sub counts, be using conditional aggregation. This means you apply a condition inside the aggregation function. `COUNT(CASE WHEN GENDER = 'Laki-Laki' THEN 1 END)` gives you the count of males in the group for instance.

At last you can count super groups by applying `SUM OVER` on the counts. Thus you can get the model's overall count for instance via `SUM(COUNT(*)) OVER (PARTITION BY model)`.

Here are two examples. Adjust them according to what you really need.

```
select
  model,
  age,
  gender,
  count(*) as count_for_model_age_and_gender,
  sum(count(*)) over (partition by model) as count_for_model,
  sum(count(*)) over (partition by model, gender) as count_for_model_and_gender,
  sum(count(*)) over (partition by model, age) as count_for_model_and_age
from edw.sio.tb_r_survey_in_operation
group by model, age, gender
order by model, age, gender;

select
  model,
  age,
  count(*) as count_for_model_and_age,
  sum(count(*)) over (partition by model) as count_for_model,
  count(case when gender = 'Laki-Laki' then 1 end) as count_male_for_model_and_age,
  count(case when gender = 'Perempuan' then 1 end) as count_female_for_model_and_age,
  sum(count(case when gender = 'Laki-Laki' then 1 end)) over (partition by model) as count_male_for_model,
  sum(count(case when gender = 'Perempuan' then 1 end)) over (partition by model) as count_female_for_model
from edw.sio.tb_r_survey_in_operation
group by model, age
order by model, age;
```